# Is there a way to execute native JS in Vue @click inline events?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vue app with the following element:

```
  <div @click="alert('test')"></div>
```

Of course, this doesn't run, I have to put the alert inside a vue method.
But... is there a way, even if a hack, to execute normal Js functions inside a @click event inline without the need to call a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of `this` within the context of an SFC's template is actually `window`, so:

```
<div @click="this.alert('test')"></div>
```

Will work.

**Update 10/28/2022**

This was a Vue 2 specific approach.

[Updated Fiddle showing it still works in Vue 2](https://jsfiddle.net/b8x0u1he/)

Comment: This no longer works for some reason....

Comment: @Nimrod5000 Answer updated with proper Fiddle.

Comment: I'm using vue 2 like the post suggested but it's still looking inside the vue functions and doesn't break out into the window scope.  From what I read it should work but it doesn't.  I think the click handler and how it scopes is the issue